# promise function not recognizing external variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

While I have been working in `python` for quite some time, I've recently started working with `javascript` for its tight integration with Web.

I am still struggling with concepts of event driven programming and promise driven function.

Anyway, Below I am using `node.js` module [is-port-reachable](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-port-reachable).
It does a good job of returning status if given host is reachable over a given port or not.
However, I need to collect combined info of host and port status.

For e.g. if I have `hosts = ['hostA' , 'hostB' ];`

I need to collect status of its port scan status as

`hosts2 = [ ('hostA' , true) , ('hostB', false)];`

With below code, I am able to get individual status of port scan for each host, but when I try to add it to array `host2`, its coming back as empty.
It seems promise function is not able to take/recognize external variable `aHost`.

```
const isPortReachable = require('is-port-reachable');

hosts = [ 'host' , 'host2'];
var hosts2  = new Array();

for ( var l = 0; l < hosts.length; l++) {
    var aHost = hosts[l];
    const myFunction = (aHost) =>{
    return isPortReachable(8443, {host: aHost})
    };
    myFunction(aHost).then(result => {
    console.log(aHost, result);
    hosts2.push((aHost,result));
    });
}
console.log(hosts2);
```

Output:
Further, Looks like `console.log(hosts2);` is getting executed before for loop.

```
node myscript.js
[]
hostA true
hostB false
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `isPortReachable` is asynchronous.

Comment: What you want is something like `Promise.all(hosts.map(myFunction)).then(hosts2 => console.log(hosts2))`.